# Raspberry pi line follower using camera

Tags: python, camera, opencv

I want to create a two-wheeled line following robot. I want to use the camera to detect a black line for the car to follow.
I have programmed the wheels so now I need to work on the line detection. I am thinking that the camera should take pictures all the time and then use OpenCV to analyze the pictures to see where the middle of the line is and then use one wheel to adjust the car to the middle of the line.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is a line follower robot?

Line follower or Line detector is an autonomous robot that follows either black line in white are or white line in the black area. The robot must be able to detect a particular line and keep following it. You can implement it by camera or IR.

---

As you specify, you want to do it by camera. In this case, you have a lot of options.

**-** [Line Following RegBot](http://rsewiki.elektro.dtu.dk/index.php/Camera_based_line_follower)
**-** [Line Following BeagleBone](http://einsteiniumstudios.com/beaglebone-opencv-line-following-robot.html)
**-** [pi_cam_line_follower](https://github.com/mattjml/pi_cam_line_follower)
**-** [Line Following Robot](https://github.com/gmueth/line-following-robot)
**-** etc.

---

The [Line Following BeagleBone](http://einsteiniumstudios.com/beaglebone-opencv-line-following-robot.html) is the better one. Shows you what do you need and the way of coding. It's using Python and OpenCV to do it,  as you wanted.